# how to check and get new message from db on real time in jquery ajax without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a project,as am trying to check new inserted messages in db for each user and echo that when the user is chat with another without refreshing the page to see the new message,but i try using setInterval but the problem is that once the user login the messages will wait for 3 seconds and disappear from the chat.

Now my question is how will i keep this message and also show new messages from db

```
 setInterval(function(){
    var id = $(".id").val();
      //alert(id);
      $.ajax({
  type:'get',
   url:"msg.php",
   data:{id:id},
   success: function(data){
   $("#msgnot").html(data);
   }

});
    },3000);

msg.php


<?php 
   session_start();
   include 'db.php';

   if(isset($_GET["id"])){
     $ids = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "select * from answers where userid='$ids' and msgstatus='0'";
       $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

      ?>
      <div id="reply"><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>"><?php echo "message from ".$rows["replyid"]; ?>
      <div id="m_active">
      <?php
         if($rows["msgstatus"] == "0"){
               echo "<strong style='width:50px;text-align:center;background:red;color:white;'>"."1"."</strong><br>";
         }else{
         }
        } 
         }
      ?></a></div></div>
```

Comment: That's because `.html()` empties the element and then appends DOM/text nodes. You should be using `.append()` instead.

Comment: rather than using .html(), use .append() -- then you construct a list without destroying existing data.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment: `.html()` will [empty your element before appending new content](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) (DOM or text nodes):

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, **any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content**.

What you want to achieve is to simply append additional content, and using `$('#msgnot').append(data)` will work for your case.

p/s: Note that you should be sanitising/stripping HTML tags from your user input on the server side, since [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will inject the string as-is, and users may exploit this to conduct XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Like Terry said:

When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content

You should be using append.
The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection

http://api.jquery.com/html/
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: yes now i use append but there is an issue the code continuously append same row but i want to check for new row an append it without refreshing the page

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us more code? (Html and what are returned from msg.php) ? with more information we could help u better

Comment: Try to alert the callback result to see if it brings different values
success: function(data){
 alert(data);
 $("#msgnot").html(data);
}